# Java Currency Converter adhering to OO (Object Oriented) principles

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, maintainability, object-oriented-analysis

A command line currency converter application that prompts for a user input of
source currency, source currency code and target currency code e.g.

```
C:\workspace> java CurrencyConverter 100.50 EUR GBP
```

The application returns the value of the source amount converted to the target currency
e.g. for the above input it returns

```
100.50 EUR = 86.33 GBP
```

After displaying the converted value the program exits.

The available exchange rates (GBP based) are in a comma separated value file. Format of this file is
COUNTRY,NAME,CODE,RATE 
e.g.

```
United Arab Emirates, Dirhams, AED, 7.2104
Australia, Dollars, AUD, 1.51239
Bosnia and Herzegovina, Convertible Marka, BAM, 2.60565
Bulgaria, Leva, BGN, 2.60948
```

I have a single java file which does the things but how can I convert it into well designed, extensible and maintainable form that adheres to good OO principals?

Should I consider any design pattern, if yes, what different types of objects/interfaces required and their relationships with each other?

Comment: This program seems small enough that you don't really need a design pattern. Maybe one method for checking the online conversion rate between two currencies, and then applying it to a number.

Comment: @Rogue I know this is a small program hence the challenge lies in visualising how and in what way this program could possibly grow in future and accordingly think a good design. Regarding your suggestion of checking online conversion there is no need for that as CSV file is provided.

Comment: Design Patterns are methods of solving specific problems, you can't go around and ask yourself if a pattern fits every piece of code you have. Although, this is quite common when you are learning design patterns. Some call this a "disease" called "patternitis".

Comment: Should the necessity arise by any new requirements, you can always refactor the program (possibly to patterns; there is a very good book "Refactoring to Patterns" by Joshua Kerievsky). Don't overplan and overoptimize at the beginning of a project; most often you get into problems you wouldn't have had otherwise. Just keep your code readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some design aspects I thought of

- Reading CSV file: Create an ExchangeRateReader **factory** so that
  exchange rates files of **various format** can be used as an input.
- (**Objectify**) ExchangeRate POJO objects contains code, name, country and rate
- Concrete **factory class** produces ExchangeRate objects reading from CSV
  file
- Use of Enum for ReaderType: CVS, TEST, EXCEL //the factory relies on
  to create appropriate instance (**concrete factory instance**)